# Trouble executing transactions on a private PoA network with blocktime set to 0

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, proof-of-authority

I'm trying to run a private PoA(Proof of Authority) network with the blockTime (clique.period in the gensis block) set to 0.

I'm testing a truffle contract against this network, and when executing the truffle commands (both truffle migrate and truffle test [of a simple contract]), the operations just seems to hang with the geth instances logging `Block sealing failed err="waiting for transactions"` and the network shows zero pending transactions.

I've tested the commands both against testrpc and the same private network with the blockTime set to 1 and it executes fine everytime. If there is something simple that I'm missing or if you could point me to the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

The private network is running three nodes (all signers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Truffle seems unable to work with blocktime = 0.

I found three solutions :

- connect to your nodes and stop the mining process (`miner.stop()`), launch truffle migrate, restart the mining process on nodes (`miner.start()`). This solution is not a success every time, I do not recommande it.
- test your smart contract on an other network (the more similar possible to your actual network like rinkeby).
- change the blocktime of your private chain.

Comment: Oh i see, thats very odd. Yeah I have been able to execute the transactions fine other networks or with a different blocktime. Have you been able to confirm that this issue is just with truffle and not with other method of creating a transaction?

Comment: I found a github issue being tracked internally at Truffle for anyone that stumbles onto this later: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/624